# Define rules for derivatives of integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I want to create a computational rule like,
$\frac{\partial}{\partial h_{i}}\int f\left(h_{i}\right)di:=\frac{\partial f\left(h_{i}\right)}{\partial h_{i}}$. This rule is somehow useful when doing models of heterogeneous agents.

To achieve this, I use the code,

```
Unprotect[D]
D[Integrate[x_, i_], p_] := D[x, p] /; ! FreeQ[p, i]
```

This works for codes like,

```
D[Integrate[f[h[i]/p a], i], h[i]]
```

which returns,
$\frac{a f'\left(\frac{a h(i)}{p}\right)}{p}$.

But inexplicably, it does not work for codes like,

```
D[Integrate[a f[h[i]/p ], i], h[i]]
```

which returns,
$\frac{a \int f'\left(\frac{h(i)}{p}\right) \, di}{p}$
.

The position of a trivial constant "a" does determine whether the rule applies.

I am confused because I think by definition, `x_` represents "anything" in mathematica. And `!FreeQ[a f[h[i]/p ], i]` is obviously True, which means the the rule should apply. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that `a f[h[i]/p` matches `x_`.  The problem is that your expression then evaluates to `a Integrate[f[h[i]/p ], i]`, which no longer matches `D[Integrate[x_, i_], p_]`.  You can fix this by instead doing

```
D[a_. Integrate[x_, i_], p_] := D[a x, p] /; ! FreeQ[p, i]
```

where we've allowed `a_` to take its default value as an argument of `Times`, which is `1`.  (See the [Optional and Default arguments tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) for more details.)

Then `D[Integrate[a f[h[i]/p], i], h[i]]` returns $\frac{a f'\left(\frac{ h(i)}{p}\right)}{p}$, as desired.

Note that you might have to deal with other ways that `Integrate` evaluates, such as threading over sums.  You may wish to avoid this by using something like  `Inactive[Integrate]` (see [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)) in place of `Integrate`.

Also note that the usual caveats that come with overloading built in symbols apply.  Eventually you could run into trouble from overloading `D`, particularly if you use somebody else's code which expects `D` to behave in the default way.

Comment: Thank you so much. That clears all my confusion.